# How do I stop the blend mode of my background from affecting everything on my page?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video, background

I'm trying to get the background animation of my site to turn the white text to black when it passes over it.

I did this by using:

```
.lay-content  {
 mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
```

However, this means that it makes my thumbnails also become inverted when the animation passes over them. I've created my site using WordPress with Lay Theme and the background video is an MP4.

I tried using:

```
#'textclass' #a {
  mix-blend-mode: difference !important;
}
```

However the custom CSS doesn't seem to pick up on the class of my text

I'm very new to all this stuff so any help would be greatly appreciated,
thank you!

Comment: Can you post the HTML structure inside '.lay-content'? If you have a video element you should target that element not the full container element

Comment: I’ve tried to set a class for the video but I haven’t been successful, I should have mentioned the site url is alfieshaw.viscomaub.co.uk

Comment: _"It makes my thumbnails also become inverted when the animation passes over them. "_ You can try using CSS `z-index` to layer elements. See this [example code](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_zindex). Put text on layer 1, animation on layer 2, and thumbnails on layer 3 (higher number = a higher layer). Are your thumbnails inside a container Div?